# How to create a fixed distance buffer with QGIS Nodebo 2.16.1

Tags: qgis, distance, buffer, qgis-processing

having opened the "variable distance buffer" window I can't set the radius. There is just no option but this actually is what I need to create a buffer with a specific radius.

Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: your variable distance comes from your field/table column attributes [in the screenshot it is 'id' currently]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `Fixed Distance Buffer` instead. That works like the previous vector geoprocessing buffer tool